# JAXB parsing "minOccours" - Problem with unmarshling

Tags: xml, xsd, jaxb, unmarshalling

I have following XSD which i used to generated JAXB objects

```
<xs:complexType name="packageType">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element ref="package" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        <xs:element ref="dependencies" minOccurs="0"/>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:NMTOKEN" use="required"/>
</xs:complexType>
```

Now, If i receive an XML

1. no **dependency** tag
2. empty **dependency** tag i.e.

Sample XML

```
<package id="FA33" required="false" empty="false">
  <dependencies />
</package>
```

In the above example, If i remove the "dependencies" empty tag, JAXB throws "unexpected end of package" error.

Since the minOccours is there, both of these scenario shouldn't make a difference. But in my case, JAXB is unable to unmarsh the given xml in ***case1*** i.e. if there is no dependency tag. If an empty dependencies tag is there then it goes fine.

Is it expected behavior or its doing something wrong?

P.S:
I am using Jaxb 1.3

Comment: Version 1.3 of the JAXB 1 reference implementation is quite old.  Are you able to upgrade to an implementation of the JAXB 2 specification: Metro, EclipseLink MOXy, Apache JaxMe, etc?

Comment: You're asking about dependency here.  In the snippet you posted there is "dependencies".  Can you post the snippet with dependency?  Maybe you're missing something there.

Comment: Upgrading to version 2 is not an option at the moment. it was a mistake, i have fixed my question replacing "dependency" with "dependencies". and a sample xml as well.

Answer (score 3):

How about using JAXB 2?

JAXB 1 used to validate on unmarshall. This was a problem since you couldn't really unmarshall invalid XML with missing mandatory elements etc.

As far as I remember, I used to solve this problem by:

- Registering an "ignoring" validation handler
- Generating schema-derived classes with a patched version of jaxb-xjc

The handler is as follows:

```
import javax.xml.bind.ValidationEventHandler;

/**
 * Validation handler which ignores all the validation events.
 */
public class IgnoringValidationEventHandler implements ValidationEventHandler {

    /**
     * Static instance.
     */
    public static final ValidationEventHandler INSTANCE = new IgnoringValidationEventHandler();

    /**
     * Simply returns <code>true</code>
     * 
     * @param event
     *            ignored;
     * @return Always returns <code>true</code>.
     */
    public boolean handleEvent(javax.xml.bind.ValidationEvent event) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Register it via `marshaller.setEventHandler(IgnoringValidationEventHandler.INSTANCE);`.

As for the patched `jaxb-xjc`, you may contact me via valikov(at)gmx.net, I can send you the jar.

Comment: the problem is that this JAXB jar is being used across the system in number of classes. I am not sure, changing one jar would affect other classes or not. Can i try the handler approach without modifying the given jar?

Comment: Well you can try, but this will still fail in many cases - for instance with mandatory elements and attributes. You should change the `jaxb-xjc` JAR which generates the classes (runtime `jaxb-impl` does not need to be changed). The problem is that "fail if mandatory element or attribute is missing" is hardwired in the generated code which is somewhat based on finite automat. When a transition fails, parsing simply can't go on. As I remember, I hacked `jaxb-xjc` to produce a more lax automat.